# MS Teams Graph API create Webinar

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-teams

The new Teams Webinar functionality is really useful. We want to be able to create webinars using graph APIs but have not seen any documentation on it.

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge, there isn't currently a way to create webinars using graph APIs. Would you kindly consider filing a feature request on [Microsoft's developer portal](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365-developer-platform/idb-p/Microsoft365DeveloperPlatform) so this can be looked into?